# Is there a shortcut to toggle "display: none/block" in element's style in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, css, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome DevTools there is a shortcut to show/hide an element:

[image]

Chrome adds `__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__` class to the element, but it is nothing more than `visibility: hidden`:

[image]

Is there similar shortcut to change element's `display: none/block` style? So on click it adds `style='display: none;'` attribute and toggles it `none/block`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a debugging stylesheet, with a rule for just this situation:

```
  .dn, .dn * {display:none !IMPORTANT}
```

Then, using your example, double-click `class="answer-summary"` and add `dn` to the class list so you have `class="answer-summary dn"`